# Can a function within a struct in Zig affect the struct itself?

Tags: zig

I'm working on a small text adventure as a way to practice Zig. In it, I want the player to be able to move from one Location to another, with the locations stored within the World Map. While I can add a line to Main that accomplishes what I'm trying to do, trying to add a function to the World Map struct will not compile.

```
pub const WorldMap = struct {
    currentLocation: *const Location = undefined,
    locations: []const Location,

    pub fn setLocation(self: WorldMap, loc: *Location) void {
        self.currentLocation = &loc;
    }

    pub fn printLocationBrief(self: WorldMap) void {
        self.currentLocation.print();
    }

    //TODO: Add method for traversing from the current location to a new one.
    //pub fn travelToFirstConn(self: WorldMap) void {
    //    self.currentLocation = self.currentLocation.connections[0].dest;
    //}
};
```

The commented out section will not compile. Meanwhile if I add essentially the same line in Main...

```
    try stdout.print("Testing first move...\n", .{});
    Map.currentLocation = Map.currentLocation.connections[0].dest;
    Map.printLocationBrief();
```

It works just fine. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mutate a Zig function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021886/how-do-i-mutate-a-zig-function-argument).

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters are [immutable](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/#Pass-by-value-Parameters) in Zig. Also, [struct methods](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/#struct) are not special, they are only namespaced functions that you can call with dot syntax.

You need to pass a [pointer](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/#Pointers) to the struct to be able to modify the struct:

```
fn travelToFirstConn(self: *WorldMap) void
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer.

```
 //TODO: Add method for traversing from the current location to a new one.
pub fn travelToFirstConn(self: *WorldMap) void {
    self.currentLocation = self.currentLocation.connections[0].dest;
}
```

This seems to work, after replacing the line of code in Main with:

```
try stdout.print("Testing first move...\n", .{});
Map.travelToFirstConn();
Map.printLocationBrief();
```

The key difference seems to be assigning Self in the function method as a pointer to itself, instead of simply self. Which seems to be a copy of the definition of the struct itself. I suppose as long as the actual instantiated struct is a var, this should work in general.